# SOLVED Create Wireless Hotspot doesn't work

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os, access-point, hotspot

I want to turn my Raspberry Pi 3b into a Wi-Fi Access Point, but i have the probleme as you can see in this image
[image]

Comment: you are connected wired (i.e. ethernet) when you do this?

Comment: yes, it is because of the ethernet cable. I was using it to SSH into my PI. The problem is solved thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this troubleshooting guide for [Raspberry OS "Buster" (Debian 10)](https://itssc.rpi.edu/hc/en-us/articles/12025528268429-Joining-a-Raspberry-Pi-running-Raspberry-OS-Buster-Debian-10-to-the-RPI-wpa2-wireless-service#:%7E:text=When%20trying%20to%20connect%20to,supports%20802.1x%20enterprise%20WiFi.)
Although it may be a different OS, it it goes over Linux [network manager GNOME](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html) which you can then use to create a [hotspot](https://gist.github.com/narate/d3f001c97e1c981a59f94cd76f041140)